# New-AzResourceGroupDeployment doesn't throw with verbose

Tags: azure, powershell, error-handling, azure-powershell

ErrorActionPreference is set to `Stop` prior to running both of these.

Terminating:

```
try {
    $deploy = New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
        -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
        @templateParameters
} catch { "printed" }
```

Non terminating:

```
try {
    $deploy = New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
        -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
        @templateParameters `
        -Verbose # added verbose switch
} catch { "not printed" }
```

EDIT: how to have verbose logging and still preserve the terminating part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2247). Despite the bug report is with 6.x version of powershell it reproduces on 5.1.x

It was fixed in 7.x.